# Updating Spring Boot dependencies from 1.5.3.RELEASE to 2.2.7.RELEASE breaks Spring App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-management

I am new to working with Spring Boot, I have copied a project from 1.5.3 and have the application running with this code for the `spring/application.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.company")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.company")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // log.info("Starting up... main args: " + Arrays.asList(args));
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");        
        // Runs Orchestration:run(args) via Spring
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                // .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) <- this part is uncommented in 2.2.7 run
                .run(args);

    }

}
```

I have a @Component class too that runs after the SpringApplicatoinBuilder is called.

```
@Component
public class Orchestration implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
       // stuff
    }

}
```

When I upgrade all of my dependencies from 1.5.3.RELEASE to 2.2.7.RELEASE in the modules pom file, the application seems to not call the Orchestration @Component anymore. I have looked at other examples and brought in the migrator dependency as mentioned in this article https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide. But have not had luck running the Spring App correctly.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

The worst part is that I don't get any compilation or runtime errors so I'm not sure what is incorrect here. Can someone more experienced in Spring 2.2.7 help me with my projects setup?

EDIT 10/13/2021 6:18pm
When updating to 2.5.5 release I do get an error message at the SpringApplicationBuilder class ...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:253)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.createSpringApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:97)
        at com.planalytics.rp.orchestration.spring.Application.main(Application.java:35)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Note: If you're making the update, you might as well update to the latest (2.5, I believe).

Comment: Good point, I was mimicking a project from 2.2.7, so I thought I would keep the dependencies similar as to not let more room for errors. I will update to 2.5.5 and try running it. I got an error when running the app, maybe you can make sense of it?

Comment: What did your dependencies look like before the change?

Comment: Before the change I set the spring.version variable to 1.5.3.RELEASE and commented out the migrator dependency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot ClassNotFoundException org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046056/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-metrics-applications)

Comment: If none of the proper answers there work let me know and I can take a look tomorrow. Really usually boils down to one of two things: (1) they decided to separate a component into a separate package and you have to add that dependency or (2) there is some old conflicting version of a package lingering causing this.

Comment: I answered a similar problem like this before with details on the steps. Might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902860/java-run-sshd-server-error-no-class-def-found/63903248#63903248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These dependencies are pulled by the Spring Boot core artifact that you declared. That is generally done via the `spring-boot-starter-parent` that you declare as the parent pom of your project.

In order to update your project to Spring 5 (the actual released version), you have to update the spring-boot-starter-parent parent declaration from 1.5.3 to 2.X (or the `spring-boot-dependencies` dependency version if you don't use the starter parent).
You can indeed read in the release note of Spring Boot 2 that :

Spring Boot 2.0 builds on and requires Spring Framework 5.

Note that updating from Spring Boot 1.5.3 to Spring Boot 2 may have as consequence some regressions for your application.
So you should take care to test carefully your application to identify all of them.
The Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide is also a good resource to ease the migration.

Here is a snippet of what you get by declaring org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE as parent of your project

```
    $ mvn dependency:tree                                                                       
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                             
[INFO]                                                                                      
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------             
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                                         
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------             
[INFO]                                                                                      
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---                      
[INFO] com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                                  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.5.RELEASE:compile            
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.5.RELEASE:compile                 
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile                
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile                 
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile               
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile          
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.5.RELEASE:compile   
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.5.5.RELEASE:compile`
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I did end up bringing in an updated version of the parent pom as a dependency to solve my issue

Comment: All the best mate